# Unity2d Pun2 rpc не синхронизирует смену спрайта

Tags: unity3d

Помогите решить проблему. Несколько дней ищу решение, но без результата.
Имеется игрок на котором весит скрипт:

```js
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Pun.UtilityScripts;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon.Realtime;

public class PlayerLvlControll : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    [SerializeField] List<Sprite> Sprites;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.CompareTag("lvl_up"))
        {
            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {
                if (Manager.PLAYERLVL < 4)
                    Manager.PLAYERLVL++;
            }
            //PhotonView pv = PhotonView.Get(this);
            //this.photonView.RPC("UpdateSpriteByLvl", RpcTarget.All);
            photonView.RPC("UpdateSpriteByLvl", RpcTarget.All);
            DelObj(coll);
        }
        if (coll.CompareTag("hi_lvl"))
        {
            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {
                if (Manager.PLAYERLVL != 4)
                {
                    Manager.PLAYERLVL = 4;
                    PhotonView pv = PhotonView.Get(this);
                    pv.RPC("UpdateSpriteByLvl", RpcTarget.All);
                }
            }
            DelObj(coll);
        }
    }

    void DelObj(Collider2D coll)
    {
        coll.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Destroy(coll.gameObject, 2f);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    void UpdateSpriteByLvl()
    {
        var playerSprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        switch (Manager.PLAYERLVL)
        {
            case 1:
                playerSprite.sprite = Sprites[0];
                gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector2(1.075f, 1.145f);
                break;
            case 2:
                playerSprite.sprite = Sprites[1];
                gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector2(1.08f, .93f);
                break;
            case 3:
                playerSprite.sprite = Sprites[2];
                gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector2(1.07f, 1f);
                break;
            case 4:
                playerSprite.sprite = Sprites[3];
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

задача данного скрипта повысить уровень игрока и изменить спрайт.
Все прекрасно работает только на клиенте игрока который зашел в триггер.
На других клиентах изменение спрайта работает некорректно или не работает вообще. Это видно на скрине[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Компонент PhotonView есть на всех объектах.
Я не понимаю почему так, что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 0):

реализовал через смену префабов с нужными спрайтами. может кому пригодится)

```js
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Pun.UtilityScripts;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Numerics;
 
public class PlayerLvlControll : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.CompareTag("lvl_up"))
        {
            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {
                if (Manager.PLAYERLVL < 4)
                {
                    Manager.PLAYERLVL++;
                    Manager.PLAYERPOS = gameObject.transform.position;
                    Manager.PLAYERROT = gameObject.transform.rotation;
                    var pView = gameObject.GetComponent<PhotonView>();
                    if (pView)
                        pView.RPC("DestroyMyself", pView.Owner);
                }
            }
            DelObj(coll);
        }
 
        if (coll.CompareTag("hi_lvl"))
        {
            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {
                if (Manager.PLAYERLVL != 4)
                {
                    Manager.PLAYERLVL = 4;
                    Manager.PLAYERPOS = gameObject.transform.position;
                    Manager.PLAYERROT = gameObject.transform.rotation;
                    var pView = gameObject.GetComponent<PhotonView>();
                    if (pView)
                        pView.RPC("DestroyMyself", pView.Owner);
                }
            }
            DelObj(coll);
        }
    }
 
    void DelObj(Collider2D coll)
    {
        coll.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Destroy(coll.gameObject, 2f);
    }
 
    [PunRPC]
    void DestroyMyself()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<Generator>().UpdatePlayerByLvl();
        PhotonNetwork.Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Manager.cs

```js
public static int PLAYERLVL = 1;

public static Vector3 PLAYERPOS;
public static Quaternion PLAYERROT;
```

Generator.cs

```js
[SerializeField] List < GameObject > Players;

public void UpdatePlayerByLvl() {
  PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Players[Manager.PLAYERLVL - 1].name, Manager.PLAYERPOS, Manager.PLAYERROT, 0);
}
```

все работает. но вопрос как реализовать смену спрайтов остается открытым..